# Writing a structure to a file giving segmentation fault after taking 1 input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, file-handling

In this program, I wanted to write the structure to `database.dat` file.
But after taking the nunmber of inputs and name the terminal is showing `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I tried different ways to fix it but each time it is the same case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct movie {
    char name[20];
    int g1, g2, g3;
};

void main() {
    int i, j, n;
    struct movie info[30];
    FILE *database; 

    database = fopen("/media/heatclif/Vivek/C\\ Programs/ESD/database.dat", "w");

    scanf("%d", &n);                        //No of inputs

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%[^\n]s", info[i].name);

        scanf("%d", &info[i].g1);
        scanf("%d", &info[i].g2);
        scanf("%d", &info[i].g3);

        fwrite(&info[i], sizeof(info[i]), 1, database);
    }
    fclose(database);
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the array `info`, as you will only have a single structure "active" at a time.

Comment: Also please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially learn how to catch crashes in a debugger to find out where it happens.

Comment: Check if `fopen` returns `NULL`. If it does, then the file could not be opened for some reason and it's pointless to fwrite to it.

Comment: actually, it takes name but after that shows segmentation fault, so there is no writing to file just after that. Taking non-array info did not help.

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: I don't get it #Jens

Comment: Are you sure that "/media/heatclif/Vivek/C\\ Programs/ESD/database.dat" is the actual path of the file?

Comment: @VivekBiswas before doing anything else test if `fopen` returns `NULL`!!

Comment: What name du you enter?

Comment: I figured out the fault in working, it is skipping  scanf("%[^\n]s",info[i].name);

Comment: The location is correct

Comment: The problem is with the line scanf("%[^\n]s", info[i].name);  If we are going to read string or character after an integer or float , we should clear the buffer .

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct movie
{
  char name[20];
  int g1, g2, g3;
};

int main()
{
  int i, n;
  struct movie info;     // you don't need an array here

  FILE *database;

  database = fopen("output", "w");

  if (database == NULL)   // check if the file could be opened
  {
    printf("Cannot open file\n");  // if not, display error message
    return 1;                      // and quit
  }

  scanf("%d", &n);                      // No of inputs

  for (i = 0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    scanf("%s", info.name);             // "%[^\n]s" is wrong here
    scanf("%d", &info.g1);
    scanf("%d", &info.g2);
    scanf("%d", &info.g3);
    fwrite(&info, sizeof(info), 1, database);
  }

  fclose(database);
}
```

Comment: Why is "%[^/n]s" wrong here, what should I do to be able to insert space in name??

Answer (score 0):

**This should resolve the issue, make sure you are entering correct path of database.dat or move the dat file to the same folder as the code and just give filename "database.dat" while opening the file.
Also, use fprintf to output elements of structure to file.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct movie
{
  char name[20];
  int g1,g2,g3;
};

void main()
{
   int i,j,n;
   struct movie info[30];

   FILE *database; 

   database=fopen("database.dat","w");


   if (database == NULL)   // check fi file is open or not.
   {
        printf("Error\n");  
        exit(1);                       
   }

   scanf("%d",&n);                      //No of inputs

   for(i=0;i<n;++i)
   {

      scanf("%s",info[i].name); `enter code here`// replace "%[^\n]s" by %s

      scanf("%d",&info[i].g1);
      scanf("%d",&info[i].g2);
      scanf("%d",&info[i].g3);


      fprintf(database,"%s",info[i].name); // write to file using fprintf
      fprintf(database,"%d",info[i].g1);
      fprintf(database,"%d",info[i].g2);
      fprintf(database,"%d",info[i].g3);

   }

   fclose(database);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need admin permissions to write to a program files folder. try the following snippet it works. I tried it.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>



    struct movie
    {
        char name[10];
        int g1,g2,g3;
    };

    int main(void) {

        int n,i,j;

    //    printf("!!!Hello World!!!\n");
    //    fflush(stdout);

        struct movie list[30];

        FILE *fptr;

        fptr  = fopen("C:/Users/yadhu/database.dat","w");

        if(fptr == NULL) {
            printf("File opening failed\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return 0;
        }

        //    printf("Enter number of inputs\n");
        //    fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d",&n);

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%s",list[i].name);
            scanf("%d%d%d",&list[i].g1,&list[i].g2,&list[i].g3);

            fwrite(&list[i],sizeof(list[i]),1,fptr);
        }


        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the line scanf("%[^\n]s", info[i].name);  read a character from input buffer and store it into temporary variable.

```
scanf("%c",&temp);
scanf("%[^\n]s", info[i].name);
```

As we enter an integer value and hit enter to read next value, compiler stores either enter or null into the string’s first character and string input terminates.

```
 scanf("%d", &n);                        //No of inputs
```

After this line when you hit enter compiler stores enter or null as info[i].name first character. Here we are reading a character from input buffer and store it into temporary variable, thus clearing input buffer before reading our string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this line

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", info[i].name);
```

Firstly, is that it has an extra an extra "s" which is why you're finding it isn't working as it is looking for an actual "s" in your input. The format string should just be `%[^\n]`.

Secondly it doesn't ensure that the string entered fits within the space available.

A potentially better way to do what you're trying to do is to use `fgets`

```
fgets(info[i].name,20,stdin);
```

This will read in a line of text, but limit it to at most 19 characters (there is always one slot used to store the `NUL` terminating character). It will stop if it encounters a `\n` but will include it in the string, so you will need to remove it if it exists.

```
if(strchr(info[i].name,'\n')) // See if there is a `\n` in the string
{
   *(strchr(info[i].name,'\n'))='\0'; // Replace with a NUL if there is
}
```

You should also check the return results of `fopen` and ensure that the file is opened before continuing.

```
if (database == NULL)   // check if the file could be opened
{
    printf("Cannot open file: %s\n",strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

You are also going to run into problems when you start to read in the second entry as you don't clear out the input buffer as there will be a `\n` after the 3rd number. Again, `fgets` could help here.

Declare a new string to store the line

```
char buffer[100];
```

And then replace the calls to `scanf` with the following. It'll read in an entire line as before and then `sscanf` will extract out the 3 numbers. It also checks that it did in fact find 3 numbers and if not, you could report an error or whatever you feel is required.

```
fgets(buffer,100,stdin);
if(sscanf(buffer,"%d%d%d",&info[i].g1,&info[i].g2,&info[i].g3)!=3)
{
    // Did not get 3 numbers - handle situation appropriately.
}
```

You're probably also need to do similar to clear out the input buffer after reading in the value of `n` too.

Since you don't appear to be using `info` except to write out the data, there isn't also much point having it as an array. Just declaring `info` as a simple struct and removing the array indexing means you won't be limited in how many entries you write out.

Answer (score 0):

The filename seems incorrect in `database = fopen("/media/heatclif/Vivek/C\\ Programs/ESD/database.dat", "w");` but you do not test `fopen` return value for failure. Hence the later call `fwrite(&info, sizeof(info), 1, database);` has undefined behavior if `database` is `NULL`.

Note also that there is an extra 's' in `scanf("%[^\n]s", info[i].name);`.  You should instead write `scanf("%19[^\n]", info[i].name);` to prevent potential buffer overflows and test the return value of `scanf` to detect invalid input.